# Percentage width list grid layout with percentage left margin on <li> and negative percentage left margin on the <ul>

Tags: css, percentage, grid-layout

Long title, sorry.

Normally when I make grid layouts using lists I have a fixed width on the `<li>` and the `<ul>`. I then have a left margin on the `<li>` which I then put as a negative left margin on the container `<ul>` thus pulling the whole thing back across and lining up perfectly.

But I can't get this to work with percentages and I don't get it.  Think I'm missing something obvious.  It should fit 3 items on one line!

Each li is 32%, and three on a row makes 96%, then a left margin of 2% makes 102%, then the negative margin-left on the ul of -2% to balance things up again.

---

**Some HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <ul>
            <li><div class="inner">Item 1</div></li>
            <li><div class="inner">Item 1</div></li>
            <li><div class="inner">Item 1</div></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Some CSS**

```
.container {
    padding: 30px;
}
.row {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
ul {
    margin: 0 0 0 -2%;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
li {
    width: 32%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 0 2%;
    list-style: none;
}
.inner {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

**And a cheeky fiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/davidpauljunior/6DEv9/

Another fiddle here to show how it works using PIXELS and negative margins. The aim is to make 3 items fit perfectly on a line.
http://jsfiddle.net/davidpauljunior/6DEv9/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused because the width of the LIs are a percentage of the parent element (in this case the UL), but the problem being is that when you put a negative margin on the parent element (in this case -2%) is makes the parent element 102%, but you calculations are still going off of the parent element being 100%, which leaves a space.  The only way to go about this and get a perfect fit is to have no negative margin on the UL, but then remove the first LI's margin using the ":first-child" selector like [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6DEv9/7/) and the code below.

```
ul {
    background-color: red;
    list-style: none outside none;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 6px 0;
}
li {
    background-color: #FFF;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 2%;
    width: 32%
}
li:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

Hope that helps,
-Elijah

Comment: It's good to get confirmation on this.  Bootstrap's 'row-fluid' uses this concept, and you quickly run into the need for `li:nth-child(3n + 4) { margin-left: 0; }`.  Unfortunately this in turn causes issues for me in more complex case where I have some hidden `<li>` elements.  Oh well, no easy way round.

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to give width in % and each item width is 32% which becomes 32*3 becomes 96% and with marign of 2% on each item it becomes total 102% and ur width is 100% and current list will always take the width according to your container width whether u use margin or not you should divide container width on total list item including with the margin 
http://jsfiddle.net/6DEv9/2/

use this

```
li {
    width: 31%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 0 2%;
    list-style: none;
}
```

Comment: I said in my question that the calculation was 102%, which is why I gave a negative margin to the container ul. You've just made the width smaller, and now they don't fit flush with the container.  An example here of it working with pixels.  Note the negative margins and how perfectly flush the list is with the parent container [http://jsfiddle.net/davidpauljunior/6DEv9/5/](http://jsfiddle.net/davidpauljunior/6DEv9/5/)

Comment: i told u in my answer that the list will behave according to the width of container not with the margin

Comment: Ok, but I don't think the answer is to make items smaller so that don't actually correctly fit the layout flush.

Comment: dear they will align according to the inner width of container nothing to do with container margin